# Detect video frame offset to sync videos the smart way

Tags: ffmpeg

When recording video, we know that it has for instance 60 fps. But do we also know, what the video offset is? We do know that the time difference between frames is 1/60 s. But when did it start as an absolute value? The problem comes into play when trying to sync two videos of the same scenery, for instance stereo with different cameras that were not frame-locked. My idea is to interpolate two - audio synced - 60 fps videos to for instance 180 fps to then change them to 60 fps again to hopefully have matching frames. This does not work, according to my test. A better solution would be to know the time difference between frames to interpolate based on difference, for instance using a deep learning algorithm.

How can ffmpeg help me here?